# How do you use a group by / having clause in a sub-query for?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to pull the `ClientID` from the following sub-query with a group by and having clause but I get the following error:

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced w ith
>   EXISTS.

Query:

```
select 
    ClientID 
from 
    SurveyResponses 
where 
     ClientID in (select ClientID, count (surveyresponseid) 
                  from SurveyResponses
                  where SurveyID in (1988,1989,2750,3206,15561) 
group by 
     ClientID
having count (SurveyResponseID) > 1) and SurveyID = 1989
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove the **count()** from the select clause

```
   select ClientID from SurveyResponses where ClientID in
    (select ClientID from SurveyResponses
    where SurveyID in (1988,1989,2750,3206,15561) 
    group by ClientID
    having count (SurveyResponseID) > 1) and SurveyID = 1989
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pulling two columns in your sub query and can only pull one, because you are telling sql, check where client ID exists in the count of survey responses AND the clientIDs in the SurveyResponses table.

Try this, it is untested

```
select ClientID from SurveyResponses 
where ClientID in (select ClientID  from SurveyResponses
where SurveyID in (1988,1989,2750,3206,15561) 
group by ClientID
having count (SurveyResponseID) > 1) and SurveyID = 1989
```

Comment: You should *not* use the `>` char before your code snippets - makes it harder to read, disables the syntax highlighting....

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this:-

```
select ClientID from SurveyResponses where ClientID in
(select ClientID from SurveyResponses
where SurveyID in (1988,1989,2750,3206,15561) 
group by ClientID
having count (SurveyResponseID) > 1) and SurveyID = 1989
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    ClientID 
from 
    SurveyResponses 
where 
     ClientID in (select ClientID,  
                  from SurveyResponses
                  where SurveyID in (1988,1989,2750,3206,15561) 
group by 
     ClientID
having count (SurveyResponseID) > 1) and SurveyID = 1989
```

This subquery is not valid cause you are selecting multiple fields `ClientID,
 count (surveyresponseid)`  . If you want to handle multiple fields in `subquery` for `Where In` condition try this .[Handling multiple columns](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4e058e95-9d7c-4baa-a73e-3c849b4c6463/handling-multiple-columns-returned-by-a-subquery-with-an-in-clause)

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers work fine, you could also use the `EXISTS` syntax:

```
SELECT clientID
FROM SurveyResponses
WHERE EXISTS (
         SELECT * 
         FROM SurveyResponses SR 
         WHERE SR.SurveyId IN (1988, 1989, 2759, 3206, 15561) 
               AND SR.ClientId = ClientID)
GROUP BY ClientID
HAVING COUNT(SurveyResponseID) > 1 AND SurveyID = 1989
```